# Problems faced by Manually Implementing a FIFOQueue in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, queue

I am trying to come up with a method that could implement a `FIFOQueue` in tensorflow. So on every iteration, the purpose is to assign a `placeholder` a certain number, then store it in a `Variable` named: ***buffer***. After each assignment, I am incrementing an index. The buffer size is [5], so that index should range from 0 to 4. Finally, after the buffer is full, I would set `buffer[0:4]` to be `buffer[1:5]`, and then add the new value to `buffer[4]`. So here is my

**code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

dim = 30

lst = []
for i in range(dim):
    lst.append(random.randint(1, 10))

data = np.reshape(lst, [dim, 1])
print(lst)

# create a buffer:
buffer_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1])

buffer = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5], tf.int32))

index = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0))

def fillBufferBeforeFilled():
    update_op1 = tf.scatter_update(buffer, indices=[index], updates=buffer_input)
    index_assign_add = tf.assign_add(index, 1)
    return update_op1, index_assign_add

def fillBufferAfterFilled():
    tmp = tf.slice(buffer, begin=[0], size=[4])
    update_op2 = tf.scatter_update(buffer, indices=[0, 1, 2, 3], updates=tmp)
    update_op3 = tf.scatter_update(buffer, indices=[index], updates=buffer_input)
    return update_op2, update_op3

cond = tf.cond(tf.equal(index, 4), lambda: fillBufferBeforeFilled(), lambda: fillBufferAfterFilled())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(dim):
        cond_ = sess.run(cond, feed_dict={buffer_input: data[i]})
        buf = sess.run(buffer, feed_dict={buffer_input: data[i]})
        print('buf: ', buf)
```

**Problem:** The `index` Variable is not incremented after each call, while the first element of the `buffer` is being assigned to the value passed to the placeholder.

I would like to know why I'm getting this behavior and what is the solution to this problem.

any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

dim = 30

lst = []
for i in range(dim):
    lst.append(random.randint(1, 10))

data = np.reshape(lst, [dim, 1])
print(lst)

# create a buffer:
buffer_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1])

buffer = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5], tf.int32))

index = tf.Variable(-1, tf.int32)

def fillBufferBeforeFilled():
    index_assign_add = tf.assign_add(index, 1)
    with tf.control_dependencies([index_assign_add]):
        update_op1 = tf.scatter_update(buffer, indices=[index], updates=buffer_input)

    return update_op1, index_assign_add

def fillBufferAfterFilled():
    tmp = tf.slice(buffer, begin=[1], size=[4])
    update_op2 = tf.scatter_update(buffer, indices=[0, 1, 2, 3], updates=tmp)
    with tf.control_dependencies([update_op2]):
        update_op3 = tf.scatter_update(buffer, indices=[index], updates=buffer_input)

    return update_op2, update_op3

cond = tf.cond(tf.equal(index, 4), lambda: fillBufferAfterFilled(), lambda: fillBufferBeforeFilled())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(dim):
        cond_ = sess.run(cond, feed_dict={buffer_input: data[i]})
        buf = sess.run(buffer, feed_dict={buffer_input: data[i]})
        print('buf: ', buf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up the order of the conditions in `tf.cond`; it should be

```
cond = tf.cond(tf.equal(index, 4), lambda: fillBufferAfterFilled(), lambda: fillBufferBeforeFilled())
```

I can get your code running and it mostly works, but the updates aren't quite right; I suspect you'll need to add some `tf.control_dependencies` calls to force things to happen in the right order.